# FakeItEasy and matching Anonymous types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, fakeiteasy

I having trouble matching an expectation that uses anonymous types.  I am new to FakeItEasy but not to mocking and would like some guidance on what is the proper way to match arguments.  I understand from this thread (https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/532#issuecomment-135968467) that the "predicate can be extracted to a method".  I have created a method that matches a Func<object, bool> signature named **IsMatch** to hide the reflection (similar to the link#comment included above) and the FakeItEasy argument parser still doesn't pick it up.  Here is a failing test.  How can I check the anonymous type?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FakeItEasy;
using Xunit;

namespace UnitTests
{
    public class Tests
    {
    private Dictionary<string, object> _properties;

    [Fact]
    public void AnonymousTest()
    {
        string id = "123456ABCD";
        string status = "New Status";

        var fake = A.Fake<IRepository>();
        var logic = new BusinessLogic(fake);

        _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"Status__c", status},
            {"UpdatedOn__c", DateTime.Today},
            {"IsDirty__c", 1},
        };

        var expectation = A.CallTo(() => fake.UpdateDatabase(id, A<object>.That.Matches(anon => IsMatch(anon))));

        logic.ChangeStatus(id, status);

        expectation.MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();
    }

    private bool IsMatch(object o)
    {
        foreach (var prop in _properties)
        {
            if (!o.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Key).GetValue(o).Equals(prop.Value))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
public interface IRepository
{
    void UpdateDatabase(string id, object fields);
}

public class BusinessLogic
{
    private IRepository _repo;
    public BusinessLogic(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(string id, string status)
    {
        var fields = new
        {
            Status__c = status,
            UpdatedOn__c = DateTime.Today,
            IsDirty__c = true
        };
        _repo.UpdateDatabase(id, fields);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@philipwolfe, the structure of your test looked right to me, so I tried it out.
It passes when I change

```
{"IsDirty__c", 1}
```

to

```
{"IsDirty__c", true}
```

to match the object built in `ChangeStatus` method.